# What is the advantage of using mode() to replace nans in columns with Dtype=object?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, mode

I am currently learning Machine Learning and I came across a tutorial where when a column is of Dtype = object the nans are replaced by the columns mode.

The particular line where this is done is:

```
test_df['MSZoning']=test_df['MSZoning'].fillna(test_df['MSZoning'].mode()[0])
```

When checking what the values of MSZoning with

```
test_df['MSZoning'].value_counts()
```

The output is

```
RL         1114
RM          242
FV           74
C (all)      15
RH           10
```

After taking the mode and filling the nans, the output seems to be the same.

It is not clear to me what mode() is actually doing here. I was wondering if someone could help me with this matter.

**The notebook of this data:** https://github.com/krishnaik06/Kaggle-Competitions/blob/master/Advance%20House%20PRice%20PRediction/HandleTestData.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this is not working for you. Mode should typically fill the missing values with the most occurring value in the column. In this case it should fill with 'RL'. Are you sure the column has missing values?

I was working this data recently and did not find any missing values in this particular column.